# Alternative to 'Code Jumper' for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, gratis, programming, visual-studio, vb.net

**[Code Jumper](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab43a471-b840-4d81-ad6f-c9f350cfcd16)** is a time-saver extension/plugin for **Visual Studio** that adds a kind of navigation panel to easily jump between the members of your code with a single click.

For big APIs it's really useful because it avoids scrolling thousands of lines, opening #regions, hidding Xml documentation, searching for a method or member name, etc... its a must-have, because It really saves a lot of time:

[image]

However, **Code Jumper** has two big problems, one is the poor performance of the extension, which slows the code when exists +1000 lines of code in a class, and the second problem is that it can't parse Vb.Net Modules, no matter what says in the product description, because the reality is that it can only parse classes (Probably the author wrote that it can parse Vb.Net because he didn't knew the existance of Vb.Net modules...)

I'm just in search for a better alternative than **Code Jumper**.

### Requisites:

- Works as a extension/plugin for **Visual Studio** +2013.
- Can parse all kind of C# and Vb.Net members. Most important: Classes, Structures, and Modules.
- Has a similar UI design/aspect as Code Jumper, 
  I mean a navigation panel in left or right lateral of the Code Editor window, or other easy accesible design.
- Has better performance than Code Jumper when working with +1000 lines of code.
- Free or paid.

Comment: Could Visual Assist help? I'm not using it any more, but I still have the license, so if it looks fine at first glance, I could try a few particaular things. It has a free trial version. http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-navigation.asp

Comment: @Thomas Thankyou for comment, but unfortunately the **VA Outline** window (the equivalent window of **Code Jumper** that shows the members of the current file), is not compatible with VB.Net language.

Comment: Doens't offer VisualStudio exactly this in the combobox above the code editor window? It contains a list of methods and properties of the open file and is placed between the code editor and the tab.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thanks for comment. Yes but it is too basic functionality, and undockable, just one member is shown until you expand the combobox, and that makes loose time. A custom implementation (like Code Jumper or Visual Assist) shows more kind of members (for example, fields, and enums), and are displayed in a flexible window that you can dock and resize in a lateral of the code editor window, or anywhere.

Comment: I use ReSharper for this kind of navigation. You press a shortcut combination, type few letters from the member name and you're where you want to be.

Comment: Thankyou but ReSharper is another C# only product, I tested it in the past and lacks of Vb.Net functionalities, just very few of the original C# features are Vb.Net compatible, also the idea is to have a visual representation of the members instead of typing the member name, I think that will make loose time when trying to find one of ten overloads, for example. Anyways, thanks again!.